# Android WebView don't show a file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I use `webview_flutter` lib. How I setup controller:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _delegate = NavigationDelegate(
      onPageFinished: (_) => setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      }),
    );
    _controller = WebViewController();

    _controller
      ..setNavigationDelegate(_delegate)
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.file.url));

    super.initState();
  }
```

The link I am passing contains a file. This works fine on ios, but on android I see a white screen and this is what's in the console:

```
updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

Comment: Tell the value of widged.file.url.

Comment: [Link](http://api-dev.spyglass-backend.secreate.dev/media/files/file-sample_1MB_NYBVWBn.doc) @blackapps

Comment: ????? Please just post the value. No links.

Comment: what do u mean? you can copy that

Comment: There is nothing to copy and the link goes to stackoverflow. So just post the url. What is the problem posting a readable url?

Answer (score 0):

Android webviews are not generic document viewers. To view files in webview on android you need the appropriate plugins

source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/143525